# Waiting Time or Response Time Distribution for M/G/1/K Queue

Tags: queueing-theory

I can't find any formulas for the LST of the waiting time distribution or the response time distribution of the M/G/1/K queue. Does anybody know any references and sources that they could point me to? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Page 8 and the references mentioned there of the following paper might be helpful to you.

[Niu, Cooper. Transform-free analysis of M/G/1/K and related queues (1991).](http://www.utdallas.edu/~scniu/documents/mg1k.pdf)